# git: could not lock config file Permission denied & Invalid argument

Tags: git

I updated node modules and after that got like 5000+ changes that need commiting, when I try to commit, I get the errors, that file names are too long. Ok so I use the command to allow long file names on windows, but then I get this error. Ideas?

```
    C:\wamp\www\site17>git config --system core.longpaths true
    error: could not lock config file c:\program files\git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: Pe
    rmission denied
    error: could not lock config file c:\program files\git\mingw64/etc/gitconfig: In
    valid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue regarding long file names. I tried below commands and it sorted my issue. Pleae try `git config core.longpaths true` and `git add .` and then `git commit`